# Importing XML PhpMyAdmin error #1064

Tags: mysql, xml, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import an XML file in PhpMyAdmin, but after execution, I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci' at line 1
```

Here is the raw XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<name>*dbname*</name>
<create>true</create>
<overwrite>false</overwrite>

<charset>utf8</charset>

<table>

    <!--
    Namespaced Key-Value Store for Application Configuration.
     - Keys are namespaced per appid.
     - E.g. (core, global_cache_gc_lastrun) -> 1385463286
    -->
    <name>*dbprefix*appconfig</name>

    <declaration>

        <field>
            <name>appid</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>32</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>configkey</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>64</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>configvalue</name>
            <type>clob</type>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
        </field>

        <index>
            <name>appconfig_appid_key_index</name>
            <primary>true</primary>
            <unique>true</unique>
            <field>
                <name>appid</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
            <field>
                <name>configkey</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>
        <index>
            <name>appconfig_config_key_index</name>
            <field>
                <name>configkey</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>
        <index>
            <name>appconfig_appid_key</name>
            <field>
                <name>appid</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>

    </declaration>

</table>

<table>

    <!--
    Bidirectional Map for Storage Names and Storage Ids.
     - Assigns each storage name a unique storage id integer.
     - Long storage names are hashed.
     - E.g.                     local::/tmp/ <-> 2
     - E.g. b5db994aa8c6625100e418406c798269 <-> 27
    -->
    <name>*dbprefix*storages</name>

    <declaration>

        <field>
            <name>id</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
            <length>64</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>numeric_id</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default>0</default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <autoincrement>1</autoincrement>
            <length>4</length>
        </field>

        <index>
            <name>storages_id_index</name>
            <unique>true</unique>
            <field>
                <name>id</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>

    </declaration>

</table>

<table>

    <name>*dbprefix*file_map</name>

    <declaration>

        <field>
            <name>logic_path</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>512</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>logic_path_hash</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>32</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>physic_path</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>512</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>physic_path_hash</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>32</length>
        </field>

        <index>
            <name>file_map_lp_index</name>
            <primary>true</primary>
            <unique>true</unique>
            <field>
                <name>logic_path_hash</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>

        <index>
            <name>file_map_pp_index</name>
            <unique>true</unique>
            <field>
                <name>physic_path_hash</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>

    </declaration>

</table>

<table>

    <!--
    Bidirectional Map for Mimetypes and Mimetype Id
     - Assigns each mimetype (and supertype) a unique mimetype id integer.
     - E.g.     application <-> 5
     - E.g. application/pdf <-> 6
    -->
    <name>*dbprefix*mimetypes</name>

    <declaration>

        <field>
            <name>id</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default>0</default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <autoincrement>1</autoincrement>
            <length>4</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>mimetype</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>255</length>
        </field>

        <index>
            <name>mimetype_id_index</name>
            <unique>true</unique>
            <field>
                <name>mimetype</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>

    </declaration>

</table>

<table>

    <!--
    Main file table containing one row for each directory and file.
     - Assigns a unique integer fileid to each file (and directory)
     - Assigns an etag to each file (and directory)
     - Caches various file/dir properties such as:
      - path (filename, e.g. files/combinatoricslib-2.0_doc.zip)
      - path_hash = md5(path)
      - name (basename, e.g. combinatoricslib-2.0_doc.zip)
      - size (for directories this is the sum of all contained file sizes)
    -->
    <name>*dbprefix*filecache</name>

    <declaration>

        <field>
            <name>fileid</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default>0</default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <autoincrement>1</autoincrement>
            <length>4</length>
        </field>

        <!-- Foreign Key storages::numeric_id -->
        <field>
            <name>storage</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>4</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>path</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
            <length>4000</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>path_hash</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>32</length>
        </field>

        <!-- Foreign Key filecache::fileid -->
        <field>
            <name>parent</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>4</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>name</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
            <length>250</length>
        </field>

        <!-- Foreign Key mimetypes::id -->
        <field>
            <name>mimetype</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>4</length>
        </field>

        <!-- Foreign Key mimetypes::id -->
        <field>
            <name>mimepart</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>4</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>size</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>8</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>mtime</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>4</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>storage_mtime</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>4</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>encrypted</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default>0</default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>4</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>unencrypted_size</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default>0</default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>8</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>etag</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
            <length>40</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>permissions</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default>0</default>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
            <length>4</length>
        </field>


        <index>
            <name>fs_storage_path_hash</name>
            <unique>true</unique>
            <field>
                <name>storage</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
            <field>
                <name>path_hash</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>

        <index>
            <name>fs_parent_name_hash</name>
            <field>
                <name>parent</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
            <field>
                <name>name</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>

        <index>
            <name>fs_storage_mimetype</name>
            <field>
                <name>storage</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
            <field>
                <name>mimetype</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>

        <index>
            <name>fs_storage_mimepart</name>
            <field>
                <name>storage</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
            <field>
                <name>mimepart</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>

        <index>
            <name>fs_storage_size</name>
            <field>
                <name>storage</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
            <field>
                <name>size</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
            <field>
                <name>fileid</name>
            </field>
        </index>

    </declaration>

</table>

<table>

    <!--
    Stores which groups have which users as members in an n:m relationship.
     - Maps group id (gid) to a set of users (uid)
     - Maps user id (uid) to a set of groups (gid) (but without index)
    -->
    <name>*dbprefix*group_user</name>

    <declaration>

        <!-- Foreign Key groups::gid -->
        <field>
            <name>gid</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>64</length>
        </field>

        <!-- Foreign Key users::uid -->
        <field>
            <name>uid</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>64</length>
        </field>

        <index>
            <name>gu_gid_uid_index</name>
            <primary>true</primary>
            <unique>true</unique>
            <field>
                <name>gid</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
            <field>
                <name>uid</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>

    </declaration>

</table>

<table>

    <!--
    Stores which groups have which users as admins in an n:m relationship.
     - Maps group id (gid) to a set of users (uid)
     - Maps user id (uid) to a set of groups (gid)

    NOTE: This could (very likely) be reduced to a single bit in group_user
          instead of repeating varchars gid and uid here
    -->
    <name>*dbprefix*group_admin</name>

    <declaration>

        <!-- Foreign Key groups::gid -->
        <field>
            <name>gid</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>64</length>
        </field>

        <!-- Foreign Key users::uid -->
        <field>
            <name>uid</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>64</length>
        </field>
        <index>
            <name>group_admin_uid</name>
            <field>
                <name>uid</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>

        <index>
            <name>ga_gid_uid_index</name>
            <primary>true</primary>
            <unique>true</unique>
            <field>
                <name>gid</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
            <field>
                <name>uid</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>

    </declaration>

</table>

<table>

    <!--
    A simple list of groups.
    -->
    <name>*dbprefix*groups</name>

    <declaration>

        <field>
            <name>gid</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>64</length>
        </field>

        <index>
            <name>groups_pKey</name>
            <primary>true</primary>
            <field>
                <name>gid</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>

    </declaration>

</table>

<table>

    <!--
    Locks held by WebDAV clients via OC_Connector_Sabre_Locks.
    -->
    <name>*dbprefix*locks</name>

    <declaration>

        <field>
            <name>id</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default>0</default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <autoincrement>1</autoincrement>
            <unsigned>true</unsigned>
            <length>4</length>
        </field>

        <!-- Foreign Key users::uid -->
        <field>
            <name>userid</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
            <length>64</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>owner</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
            <length>100</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>timeout</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
            <unsigned>true</unsigned>
            <length>4</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>created</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
            <length>8</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>token</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
            <length>100</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>scope</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
            <length>1</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>depth</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
            <length>1</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>uri</name>
            <type>clob</type>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
        </field>

    </declaration>

</table>

<table>

    <!--
    Namespaced Key-Value Store for User Preferences
     - Keys are namespaced per userid and appid.
     - E.g. (admin, files, cache_version) -> 5
    -->
    <name>*dbprefix*preferences</name>

    <declaration>

        <!-- Foreign Key users::uid -->
        <field>
            <name>userid</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>64</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>appid</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>32</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>configkey</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>64</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>configvalue</name>
            <type>clob</type>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
        </field>

        <index>
            <name>pref_userid_appid_key_index</name>
            <primary>true</primary>
            <unique>true</unique>
            <field>
                <name>userid</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
            <field>
                <name>appid</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
            <field>
                <name>configkey</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>

    </declaration>

</table>

<table>

    <!--
    WebDAV properties.
    -->
    <name>*dbprefix*properties</name>

    <declaration>

        <field>
            <name>id</name>
            <autoincrement>1</autoincrement>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default>0</default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>4</length>
        </field>

        <!-- Foreign Key users::uid -->
        <field>
            <name>userid</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>64</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>propertypath</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>255</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>propertyname</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>255</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>propertyvalue</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>255</length>
        </field>

        <index>
            <name>property_index</name>
            <field>
                <name>userid</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>

    </declaration>

</table>

<table>

    <!--
    Shares of all types (user-to-user, external-via-link, etc.)
    -->
    <name>*dbprefix*share</name>

    <declaration>

        <field>
            <name>id</name>
            <autoincrement>1</autoincrement>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default>0</default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>4</length>
        </field>

        <!-- Constant OCP\Share::SHARE_TYPE_* -->
        <field>
            <name>share_type</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default>0</default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>1</length>
        </field>

        <!-- Foreign Key users::uid or NULL -->
        <field>
            <name>share_with</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
            <length>255</length>
        </field>

        <!-- Foreign Key users::uid -->
        <field>
            <name>uid_owner</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>64</length>
        </field>

        <!-- Foreign Key share::id or NULL -->
        <field>
            <name>parent</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
            <length>4</length>
        </field>

        <!-- E.g. file or folder -->
        <field>
            <name>item_type</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>64</length>
        </field>

        <!-- Foreign Key filecache::fileid -->
        <field>
            <name>item_source</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
            <length>255</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>item_target</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
            <length>255</length>
        </field>

        <!-- Foreign Key filecache::fileid -->
        <field>
            <name>file_source</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
            <length>4</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>file_target</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
            <length>512</length>
        </field>

        <!-- Permission bitfield -->
        <field>
            <name>permissions</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default>0</default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>1</length>
        </field>

        <!-- Time of share creation -->
        <field>
            <name>stime</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default>0</default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>8</length>
        </field>

        <!-- Whether the receiver accepted the share, if share_with is set. -->
        <field>
            <name>accepted</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default>0</default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>1</length>
        </field>

        <!-- Time of share expiration -->
        <field>
            <name>expiration</name>
            <type>timestamp</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>token</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
            <length>32</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>mail_send</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default>0</default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>1</length>
        </field>

        <index>
            <name>item_share_type_index</name>
            <field>
                <name>item_type</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
            <field>
                <name>share_type</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>
        <index>
            <name>file_source_index</name>
            <field>
                <name>file_source</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>
        <index>
            <name>token_index</name>
            <field>
                <name>token</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>
    </declaration>

</table>

<table>

    <!--
    Scheduled background jobs.
    See OC\BackgroundJob\JobList.
    -->
    <name>*dbprefix*jobs</name>

    <declaration>

        <field>
            <name>id</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default>0</default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <autoincrement>1</autoincrement>
            <unsigned>true</unsigned>
            <length>4</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>class</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>255</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>argument</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>256</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>last_run</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>false</notnull>
        </field>

        <index>
            <name>job_class_index</name>
            <field>
                <name>class</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>

    </declaration>

</table>

<table>

    <!--
    List of usernames, their display name and login password.
    -->
    <name>*dbprefix*users</name>

    <declaration>

        <field>
            <name>uid</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>64</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>displayname</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <length>64</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>password</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>255</length>
        </field>

        <index>
            <name>users_pKey</name>
            <primary>true</primary>
            <field>
                <name>uid</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>

    </declaration>

</table>

<table>

    <!--
    List of tags (category) + a unique tag id (id) per user (uid) and type.
    -->
    <name>*dbprefix*vcategory</name>

    <declaration>

        <field>
            <name>id</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <default>0</default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <autoincrement>1</autoincrement>
            <unsigned>true</unsigned>
            <length>4</length>
        </field>

        <!-- Foreign Key users::uid -->
        <field>
            <name>uid</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>64</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>type</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>64</length>
        </field>

        <field>
            <name>category</name>
            <type>text</type>
            <default></default>
            <notnull>true</notnull>
            <length>255</length>
        </field>

        <index>
            <name>uid_index</name>
            <field>
                <name>uid</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>

        <index>
            <name>type_index</name>
            <field>
                <name>type</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>

        <index>
            <name>category_index</name>
            <field>
                <name>category</name>
                <sorting>ascending</sorting>
            </field>
        </index>

    </declaration>
</table>

<table>

    <!--
    Object-Tag associations per tag type.
    -->
    <name>*dbprefix*vcategory_to_object</name>

    <declaration>

    <field>
        <name>objid</name>
        <type>integer</type>
        <default>0</default>
        <notnull>true</notnull>
        <unsigned>true</unsigned>
        <length>4</length>
    </field>

    <!-- Foreign Key vcategory::id -->
    <field>
        <name>categoryid</name>
        <type>integer</type>
        <default>0</default>
        <notnull>true</notnull>
        <unsigned>true</unsigned>
        <length>4</length>
    </field>

    <field>
        <name>type</name>
        <type>text</type>
        <default></default>
        <notnull>true</notnull>
        <length>64</length>
    </field>

    <index>
        <primary>true</primary>
        <unique>true</unique>
        <name>category_object_index</name>
        <field>
            <name>categoryid</name>
            <sorting>ascending</sorting>
        </field>
        <field>
            <name>objid</name>
            <sorting>ascending</sorting>
        </field>
        <field>
            <name>type</name>
            <sorting>ascending</sorting>
        </field>
    </index>

    <index>
        <name>vcategory_objectd_index</name>
        <field>
            <name>objid</name>
            <sorting>ascending</sorting>
        </field>
        <field>
            <name>type</name>
            <sorting>ascending</sorting>
        </field>
    </index>

    </declaration>

</table>

<table>

    <!--
    Namespaced Key-Value Store for arbitrary data.
     - Keys are namespaced per userid and appid.
     - E.g. (admin, files, foo) -> bar
    -->
    <name>*dbprefix*privatedata</name>

    <declaration>

    <field>
        <name>keyid</name>
        <type>integer</type>
        <default>0</default>
        <notnull>true</notnull>
        <unsigned>true</unsigned>
        <length>4</length>
        <autoincrement>1</autoincrement>
    </field>

    <!-- Foreign Key users::uid -->
    <field>
        <name>user</name>
        <type>text</type>
        <default></default>
        <notnull>true</notnull>
        <length>64</length>
    </field>

    <field>
        <name>app</name>
        <type>text</type>
        <default></default>
        <notnull>true</notnull>
        <length>255</length>
    </field>

    <field>
        <name>key</name>
        <type>text</type>
        <default></default>
        <notnull>true</notnull>
        <length>255</length>
    </field>

    <field>
        <name>value</name>
        <type>text</type>
        <default></default>
        <notnull>true</notnull>
        <length>255</length>
    </field>

    <index>
        <primary>true</primary>
        <unique>true</unique>
        <name>keyid_index</name>
        <field>
            <name>keyid</name>
            <sorting>ascending</sorting>
        </field>
    </index>

    </declaration>

</table>

    <table>
            <name>*dbprefix*pending_regist</name>
            <declaration>
                    <field>
                            <name>email</name>
                            <type>text</type>
                            <default></default>
                            <notnull>true</notnull>
                            <length>64</length>
                    </field>
                    <field>
                            <name>token</name>
                            <type>text</type>
                            <default></default>
                            <notnull>false</notnull>
                            <length>256</length>
                    </field>
                    <field>
                            <name>requested</name>
                            <type>integer</type>
                            <default></default>
                            <notnull>true</notnull>
                    </field>
                    <index>
                            <name>pending_regist_pKey</name>
                            <primary>true</primary>
                            <field>
                                    <name>requested</name>
                                    <sorting>descending</sorting>
                            </field>
                    </index>
            </declaration>
    </table>
```

Is there any way I can convert the XML into SQL? I need to make a cloud server using ownCloud, although some things must be modified. I tried reintalling the package, but for some reason, the database won't recreate itself... Any ideas?
My initial goal is to create a "pending" table with the users that are pending to creation.

Thanks a bunch!
Greetings from Romania!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpMyAdmin expects a certain XML format to be able to import it. To see what's expected, create a simple table in phpMyAdmin with a few columns, insert some data and export it, choosing XML.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by completely purging the ownCloud package and reinstalling it. Thanks for the tip, I'll keep in mind next time